# Ambiguous constructor call (I assume)

Tags: c++, ambiguous

I have a matrix class defined like so:

```
template <typename T, unsigned int N, unsigned int M>
class TMatrixNxM //Rows x columns
{
public:
    TMatrixNxM(T = T(0)); //Default constructor
    TMatrixNxM(const std::array<std::array<T, M>, N>&); //Construct from array
    TMatrixNxM(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<T>>); //Initializer

    //...
private:
    std::array<std::array<T, M>, N> data; //ROW-MAJOR
};
```

Now, in the code which uses matrices I have:

```
Math::Matrix3x3 b({{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}});
```

(Note: *Matrix3x3* is a typedef for *TMatrixNxM< float, 3, 3>* and also, it is in a *Math* namespace)

Until now, it worked, because I didn't always have that array constructor, only initializer list one. But now, however, the compiler doesn't even finish compiling, it **crashes**! (I get "stopped working" popup and I have to close it, I am using MS VS Express 2013)

If I do it like this:

```
Math::Matrix3x3 b = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
```

Then it works fine. This is what I **assume**:

When I do it like that, then there is no ambiguity since you can only call the *initializer_list* constructor that way. With the first approach the compiler may be confused, since *array* is an aggregate type which means the initialization starts with double braces like: {{...}}, but also since I have an initializer list of initializer lists I have to use double braces. But should it really be a problem, since I never actually do double braces, those are single-braced lists inside a larger single-braces list?

What is really happening here and how do I solve this problem?

Thank you for your time!

**EDIT**

Compiler doesn't crash anymore if I make the constructor take the array by const pointer (since I'm never really going to straight-out plop the array in the constructor call, I have initializer list for that):

```
TMatrixNxM(const std::array<std::array<T, M>, N>*);
```

However can someone explain what was an actual problem before, was my assumption right?

Here's a minimal compilable (or, well, not) code that you can use to test:

```
#include <array>
#include <initializer_list>

template <typename T, unsigned int N, unsigned int M>
class TMatrixNxM //Rows x columns
{
public:
    TMatrixNxM(T = T(0));
    TMatrixNxM(const std::array<std::array<T, M>, N>&);
    TMatrixNxM(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<T>>);
private:
    std::array<std::array<T, M>, N> data; //ROW-MAJOR
};

template <typename T, unsigned int N, unsigned int M>
TMatrixNxM<T, N, M>::TMatrixNxM(T par_value)
{
    std::array<T, M> temp;
    temp.fill(par_value);
    data.fill(temp);
}


template <typename T, unsigned int N, unsigned int M>
TMatrixNxM<T, N, M>::TMatrixNxM(const std::array<std::array<T, M>, N> &par_values)
{
    data = par_values;
}


template <typename T, unsigned int N, unsigned int M>
TMatrixNxM<T, N, M>::TMatrixNxM(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<T>> par_values)
{
    int i = 0;

    for(std::initializer_list<T> row : par_values)
    {
        int j = 0;

        for(T value : row)
        {
            data[i][j] = value;
            ++j;
        }

        ++i;
    }
}

int main()
{
    TMatrixNxM<float, 3, 3> b({{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}});

    return 0;
}
```

If you comment out the constructor declaration/definition with arrays then it should compile and execute fine. As stated previously, I am using compiler from MS VS Express 2013.

Comment: You're going to have to provide a small but complete sample of code that exhibits your problem (i.e. that someone else can compile).   From the partial information you've provided, I can't see a problem .... and neither can my compiler.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Alrighty, there it is

Comment: Is it necessary to copy the array twice in the constructor? Do you know what pass by value does?

Comment: I know, I used to do it by const reference, but then I removed it for testing and forgot to add it back

Comment: But even with const reference it doesn't compile, so doesn't matter really

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, looks like it just doesn't work on Microsoft's compiler. I tried to compile the same code on my Linux machine that uses GCC and it compiles with no problems. And it is indeed calling the initializer list constructor as it should. If I make an array in a variable and pass it, it also compiles fine, and it calls the array constructor:

```
std::array<float, 3> a = {{1, 2, 3}};
std::array<std::array<float, 3>, 3> b = {{a, a, a}};

TMatrixNxM<float, 3, 3> mat(b);
```

It also compiles and calls the array constructor if I initialize the array directly:

```
TMatrixNxM<float, 3, 3> mat({{ {{1, 2, 3}}, {{4, 5, 6}}, {{7, 8, 9}}  }});
```

Comment: So... GCC says A, Microsoft says B, therefore Microsoft has a bug? It doesn't work like that. Microsoft doesn't have to be compatible with GCC, and doesn't even try to. It does try to implement the C++ standard. So does GCC. And both have bugs. It's just possible that the bug is in GCC here, or that the standard leaves the behaviour unspecified or undefined, you'd have to check the standard to see what it actually says.

Comment: FWIW, on my VS2013, I get "fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler. (compiler file 'f:\dd\vctools\compiler\cxxfe\sl\p1\c\p1_init.c', line 3999)", and internal compiler errors *do* always point to a bug in the compiler, regardless of whether the code is valid. I do think your conclusion that MS has a bug was right, I just think your reasons for coming to that conclusion were wrong.

Comment: @BenVoigt That's what I said: "internal compiler errors do always point to a bug in the compiler, regardless of whether the code is valid."